# MultiComboxBox within a table closes after selection

Tags: sapui5

I have tried to resolve the problem for quite sometime but have not been successful.

Inside a table, I have a `sap.m.MultiComBox`. The drop down in the multicombobox closes after selecting the first value. If not inside the table, the multicombobox works fine as expected (popover does **not** close). One additional behavior I observed is that if I don't have the `selectedKeys` bound, then it works fine.

Any reasons or suggestions?

```xml
<Table
  growing="true"
  items="{employee>/EmployeeCollection}">
  <columns>
    <Column width="10%" />
    <Column width="55%" />
    <Column width="35%"/>
  </columns>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <Image id="image" src="{employee>dataURI}" class="sapOB_Assign_Usercircle" />
    <Text text="{employee>Name}" class="tableText" />
    <VBox>
      <MultiComboBox id="mcb1"
        selectedKeys="{employee>roles}"
        items="{
          path: 'roles>/BusinessRoles',
          templateShareable: false
        }">
        <core:Item key="{roles>id}" text="{roles>name}" />
      </MultiComboBox>
      <HBox />
    </VBox>
  </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the behavior. With which UI5 version is the app running? You can find it out by pressing [Ctrl] + [Left Alt] + [Shift] + [P].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using UI5 version 1.66 or below with `growing="true"` on the Table. In that case, the dropdown closes immediately after the selection due to a focus loss caused by rerendering of the list item (Its DOM element being rewritten completely). The rerendering itself is caused by two-way bound `selectedKeys` which explains why it "works" if the property is not bound.

Normally, two-way binding should not be used together with `growing`. According to the [API reference](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/081380dda719d294c3d24f20ff4ac6cd07399882/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/ListBase.js#L181):

> **Note:** Growing must **not** be used together with two-way binding.

But it's still unclear whether the above constraint is still valid today (See [issue #3013](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3013)).

In order to keep two-way binding with `growing="true"`, add the attribute `key`* to the list binding info:

```xml
<Table
  growing="true"
  items="{
    path: 'employee>/EmployeeCollection',
    key: 'employeeId'
  }"
>
```

Here is a **working example: https://jsbin.com/ciyosir/edit?js,output**. As you can see, the dropdown is kept open even after selection because the list item is not rerendered thanks to the *extended change detection*.

Additionally, I'd suggest to upgrade to the latest stable UI5 version in order to benefit from many controls having migrated to the new *[semantic rendering](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/04/20/ui5-in-2020-and-beyond/#:%7E:text=The%20UI5%20Rendering)*.

---

<sup>* The `key` awaits a property name from the model of which the value is unique. For more information, see topic [*Extended Change Detection*](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/7cdff73f308b4b10bdf7d83b7aba72e7).</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much Boghyon Hoffmann. The key works like a charm!  As you have said , this is an issue with 1.60 and works fine from 1.71 and above. As I could not change the version of the sap.ui, I am going ahead with your solution. Thanks for taking the additional effort in explaining about the two-way binding and the extended change detection.